# ActiveJob/Resque dirty reads. Transaction isolation level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

I have several Resque workers for the same entity(User). After successful processing it should decrease `call_left` attribute.

It works perfectly with `perform_now`(consequently), but produces unpredictable results with `perform_later`(in parallel). In logs there are commits with the same number of `calls_left`.

I tried to use `reload` method and even set the highest isolation level. But still have this problem.

How to solve?

```
class DataProcessJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default    
  def perform(user_id, profile_id)
    User.transaction(isolation: :serializable) do
      user = User.find(user_id).reload
      user.data_process(profile_id)
      user.update(calls_left: user.calls_left-1)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option would be to use *locking* ([optimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) or [pessimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)). The documentation explains their differences and you can choose the one that suits your case. Also, [here is a relevant code snippet](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) from the docs that would probably help you if you'd go with the optimistic locking.

```
def with_optimistic_retry
  begin
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
    begin
      # Reload lock_version in particular.
      reload
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      # If the record is gone there is nothing to do.
    else
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

The second option would be to increment the `calls_left` field using raw SQL string query. The underlying DB would deal with atomic updates.

---

Last, but not least, you could use [`decrement!(:calls_left)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-decrement-21) method to make your code more readable.

Comment: locks don't work. optimistic one doesn't work because it is designed to work in single process. pessimistic one – just doesn't.
Raw SQL seems to work, thanks.

Comment: Actually, Rails implements optimistic locking by adding `lock_version` field to your table (slightly different from DB level optimistic locking). So, it would work in non single process scenarios if they implemented checking the lock version in SQL update query. But, I am not sure, haven't looked into the source code. Did you try using optimistic locking? If you did and it didn't work, please let me know. It'd be nice to take note of this for the future.

Comment: Optimistic locking is turned on by default. It raises `rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` if object is outdated, which is not true in my case. 
And this is from documentation:
`This locking mechanism will function inside a single Ruby process. To make it work across all web requests, the recommended approach is to add lock_version as a hidden field to your form.`